# Rows are duplicated when I have already used idPrefix

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

On a single page, I have multiple grids where some of the values are same/queried from the same database. While the grid keeps refreshing itself, I get duplicate rows. Why is that? The duplicate rows disappear when I hard refresh the page.

I have used:

```
idPrefix: $(gridObject).attr('id') + "_" 
// gridObject is a reference to a particular jqGrid
```

for each `jqGrid` on the page, but the row id's are duplicated as shown below:

[image]

A snapshot of what the interface looks like:

[image]

There should be only 2 group headers `dhoop` and `afshan`. What could be the reason for this? I am using `jqGrid  4.6.0`

Comment: could you provide **the demo** (in jsfiddle for example) which reproduces the problem? The test data and options of the grid are required. One should be sure that **input data** have no id duplicates (like two input items with the same id equial to 1) and one need see how you fill the grid. By the way do you tried that the same problem exist if you use latest free [jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) which describes URLs which you need temporary use for the test.

Comment: @Oleg This is the php function for one grid : http://pastebin.com/tt2vEMwz . This(http://pastebin.com/gPtpSsqH) and another file (http://pastebin.com/2JtTX1Uv) contains grid js functionality. I have mentioned the final json. I tried the new `.js of jqgrid` but couldn't use due to compatibility issues with the present code. The duplicacy  doesn't occur all the time but randomly!

Comment: Sorry, but it's fragments of your code. I asked you for the demo (in jsFiddle for example) which one can debug. The code don't contains and input data. The comment like `,{"JobID":" ","FileName":" ","StartIndex":" ","EndIndex":" ","SplitIndex":" ","Duration":" ","FileSize":" ","LogStatus":" ","Name":"dhoop"}` don't shows which **ids** exist in your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to write too much critic about the code which you posted. I describe only the part which concerned the problem which you posted.

It seems to me that the server code returns incorrect data to jqGrid. You loads the data from the server (`datatype` is not `"local"`). It means that the server code have to prepare the data for grouping. It's important to understand two base things for loading the data:

- the items of data have to have unique ids and you should correctly inform jqGrid which value from the item is the id.
- the data returned from the server have to be correctly sorted.

It you for example use the options `groupingView: {groupField: "column1", ...}` and `sortname: "column2"` then the data have to be sorted by `column1, column2` on the server. I mean that the first sorting criteria have to be the grouping field (fields) (the column `column1`) and the second sorting criteria have to be `column2` (from `sortname: "column2"`). I suppose that the data are incorrectly sorted on the backend. Your problem description: "I get duplicate rows. Why is that? The duplicate rows disappear when I hard refresh the page." let to suppose this.

Seconds, you wrote in the comment to your question, that the format of every item of returned data looks like `{"JobID":"1","FileName":" ","StartIndex":"0","EndIndex":"0","SplitIndex":"0","Duration":"0","FileSize":"0","LogStatus":" ","Name":"afshaan"}`.  I can guess that the value from `JobID` property is unique for every item. In the case the correct `jsonReader` would be

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "JobID"
}
```

The `jsonReader` informs jqGrid how to parse the items of input data. You use the following `jsonReader` instead

```
jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    records: "records",
    viewrecords: true,
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: "",
    id: "0"
}
```

which seems be wrong.

Moreover you use `datatype` parameter of jqGrid defined as function. All code example which I see on stackoverflow and which uses `datatype` as function was wrong. The examples come from some old demos created for very old version of jqGrid (version 3.6 or earlier). I would strictly recommend you to use `datatype: "json"` instead. It seems to me that you need just add the option `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }` and to use correct `jsonReader`. I can guess that it could be something like

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "responseJSON.rows",
    page: "responseJSON.page",
    total: "responseJSON.total",
    records: "responseJSON.records",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "JobID"
}
```