# GroupHeader gets duplicated on grid refresh

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

`GroupHeader` in my `jqGrid4.6.0` gets duplicated sometimes, when I keep refreshing the grid.

```
var setGridRefreshTimer = function(grid_id,interval_in_seconds) {

if(!interval_in_seconds)
    interval_in_seconds = 5;
var timerID = setInterval(function() {
    var grid = $("#"+grid_id);
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
},interval_in_seconds*1000);

return timerID;

};
```

I do not know the reason.

Following is the function that loads data into the `jqGrid`:

```
datatype:   function(postdata){
                var ts = gridObject;  // cache 'gridObject' to use later in the complete callback
                var p = gridObject.p; // cache the grid parameters
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:$(gridObject).attr('url'),
                    data:postdata,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType:"json",
                    complete: function(jsondata,stat){
                      if(stat=="success") {
                            TotalPages      =   jsondata.responseJSON.total;
                            ResponseData    =   jsondata.responseJSON.rows;
                            var thegrid     = jQuery('#'+$(gridObject).attr('id'))[0];
                            thegrid.addJSONData(jsondata.responseJSON);
                            // call loadComplete
                            if($.isFunction(p.loadComplete)) {
                                p.loadComplete.call(ts,jsondata.responseJSON);
                            }
                      }
                   }
                });
            }
```

Here is the snapshot of the `jsondata` received in function complete:

[image]

But here is a snapshot of what grid looks like after refresh:

[image]

The first row is a duplicate of the second group header. Why is this happening?

Complete `js` wrapper that I am working with:

```
var USER_GRID_UNIQUE_ID ;
    var ciRow,ciCol;

    $(function(){
        RenderJQGrids();
    });

    var RenderJQGrids = function(){     
        $('.convertTojqGrid').each(function(){
            customJqgrid($(this)[0]);
        });
    };

    var ResizeTable = function(Table)
    {
        var TableHeight     =   Table.height();
        var MaxDivHeight    =   Element('contentPANE').clientHeight;
        var MaxDivWidth     =   Element('contentPANE').clientWidth;
        var SetHeight       =   MaxDivHeight*$(Table).attr('gridHeight');
        var SetWidth        =   MaxDivWidth*$(Table).attr('gridWidth');
        Table.jqGrid('setGridHeight', SetHeight);
        Table.jqGrid('setGridWidth', SetWidth);
    };

    var fetchjqGridObject = function(gridObject){
        return {
                /**
                 * If we use datatype as function our code is responsible for calling of 'loadComplete'.
                 * For datatype as function our code is responsible for some things, which jqGrid will do it 
                 * automatically. 
                 */
                datatype:   function(postdata){
                    var ts = gridObject;  // cache 'gridObject' to use later in the complete callback
                    var p = gridObject.p; // cache the grid parameters
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:$(gridObject).attr('url'),
                        data:postdata,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType:"json",
                        complete: function(jsondata,stat){
                          if(stat=="success") {
                                TotalPages      =   jsondata.responseJSON.total;
                                ResponseData    =   jsondata.responseJSON.rows;
                                var thegrid     = jQuery('#'+$(gridObject).attr('id'))[0];
                                thegrid.addJSONData(jsondata.responseJSON);
                                // call loadComplete
                                if($.isFunction(p.loadComplete)) {
                                    p.loadComplete.call(ts,jsondata.responseJSON);
                                }
                          }
                       }
                    });
                },
                colNames:$(gridObject).attr('colNames').split(','),
                colModel:window[$(gridObject).attr('colModel')](),
                jsonReader : {
                     root: "rows",
                     records: "records",
                     viewrecords: true,
                     repeatitems: true,
                     cell: "",
                     id: "0"
                },
                idPrefix: $(gridObject).attr('id') + "_",
                rowNum:20,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                gridview: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                autoencode: true,
                toolbarfilter: true,
                //loadonce: true,   If this is on the total pages in pager wouldn't work well. This will load records at once only
                emptyrecords: "No records found",
                autowidth: true,
                shrinktoFit: true,
                forceFit: true,
                pager : '#gridpager_'+$(gridObject).attr('id'),
                pagerpos:'center',
                recordpos: 'right',
                scrollOffset: 0,
                viewrecords: true,
                pginput : true,
                sortname: $(gridObject).attr('sortBy'),
                sortorder: 'asc',
                toolbar: getToolbarProp(gridObject),
                cellsubmit: 'remote',
                cellurl:$(gridObject).attr('eurl') ? $(gridObject).attr('eurl') : "",
                cellEdit: $(gridObject).attr('cellSelector') != null,
                grouping: $(gridObject).attr('grouping') != null,
                groupingView : {
                    groupField : getGroupFields(gridObject) ,
                    groupDataSorted : true,
                    groupColumnShow : getGroupColumnShow(gridObject),
                    groupCollapse : false
                },
                onClickGroup: function(hid) {
                    /* Fired when group header is toggled */
                },
                onSelectRow : function(id) {
                    $(gridObject).setSelection(id,false);
                    $(gridObject).find('#'+id).find("input[type='radio']").prop('checked',true);
                },
                formatCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    /* You can change the cell value here which will be used in the edit mode */
                    return value.replace('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>'," ")
                },
                beforeEditCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) { 
                    /*  Just before the cell jumps into edit mode this event is fired */
                    var attr = $(gridObject).attr('editable');
                    if(typeof attr != typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
                        // Clear GridRefreshTimer
                        clearGridRefreshTimer(edRefreshTimerID);
                    }
                },
                afterEditCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    /* Just after the input element is created this event will be fired */
                    ciRow = iRow;
                    ciCol = iCol;
                },
                beforeSaveCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    /* Fires before the cell is saved, you can save the value here which is send to the server. */
                },
                beforeSubmitCell : function(rowid,cellname,value,iRow,iCol) {
                    /*
                     *  Fires before value will be send to the server, you can add extra parameters 
                     *  here to the request by returning an array.
                     */
                    var rdata = $(gridObject).getRowData(rowid);
                    var i = $(rdata.JobID).val();
                    return {jid: i,param: cellname}; // Modify the POST Request 
                },
                afterSaveCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    /**
                     *  Fires when the value of the cell is saved
                     */
                    var attr = $(gridObject).attr('editable');
                    if(typeof attr != typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
                        // Reset GridRefreshTimer
                        edRefreshTimerID = setGridRefreshTimer($(gridObject).attr('id'));
                    }

                },
                gridComplete: window[$(gridObject).attr('gridComplete')].gridComplete,
                loadComplete: function() {
                    var gridParams = $(gridObject).jqGrid('getGridParam');
                    if(gridParams.scrollTopPosition != undefined) {
                        /*
                         * scrollTopPosition is set before grid refresh.
                         * Maintain scroll state of the grid
                         */
                        $(gridObject).closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(gridParams.scrollTopPosition);
                    }
                }       

            };
    };

    var getToolbarProp  =   function(gridObject){
        var defaultProp =   [false,'top'];
        if(gridObject.hasAttribute('gridToolbar_Visible'))
            defaultProp =   [true,gridObject.getAttribute('gridToolbar_Visible')];
        return defaultProp;
    };

    var customJqgrid = function(gridObject){
        var GridUniqueid    =   $(gridObject).attr('id');
        var ResponseData    =   "";
        var TotalPages;
        var jqgridOBJECT = fetchjqGridObject(gridObject);
        $('#'+GridUniqueid).jqGrid(jqgridOBJECT);
    };

    var getGroupFields = function(gridObject) {
        if($(gridObject).attr('grouping'))
            return $(gridObject).attr('grouping').split(',');
    };

    var getGroupColumnShow = function(gridObject) {
        var groupColShowProperties = new Object;
        groupColShowProperties.Name = false;
        groupColShowProperties.PartNumber = false;

        var showProp = [];
        if($(gridObject).attr('grouping')) {
            if($(gridObject).attr('grouping').indexOf(',') != -1) {
                for(key in groupColShowProperties) {
                    showProp.push(groupColShowProperties[key]);
                }
            }else {
                showProp.push(groupColShowProperties[$(gridObject).attr('grouping')]);
            }
        }else {
            showProp.push(groupColShowProperties.Name);
        }
        return showProp;
    };


    $(window).on('resize.jqGrid',function(event) {
        var gridList = $('.convertTojqGrid').not('.relativeToParent');
        gridList.each(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('body').width() - 50);
        });

        gridList = $('.convertTojqGrid.relativeToParent');
        gridList.each(function(){
    //      $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('body').width() - 50);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I wrote you before that the most problems, which you have, are because of the usage of `datatype` defined as the function. I posted you how one can use `datatype: "json"` instead, You need just add `ajaxGridOptions` and fix `jsonReader`. In any way, can you provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem which you describe in the question?

Comment: @Oleg I noticed that, `aftersavecell` was being called twice. One because of handler and second because of the default behavior. I changed it with `event.stopPropogation` and I have noticed problems since.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. You write in the title of the question: "GroupHeader gets duplicated on grid refresh". It sound for me like the problem with **filling of the grid** and is independent from editing. You don't mention any problem with `afterSaveCell` in the text of your question. I ask you that I can help you **only if you will provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem**.

Comment: Moreover you should understand, that the problem can be fixed only if it is exist in *your code*. If the reason of the problem is in jqGrid bug, then nobody will create the fix for jqGrid 4.6. You will have to update to either free jqGrid or to Guriddo jqGrid JS. The bug can be fixed only in one from the current version of there two current forks of jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg I have changed my implementation for datatype as function to [serializeGridData](http://pastebin.com/PY8PgBwf) Have I implemented it correctly?

Comment: The code is wrong. You used `data:postdata` as the parameter in `$.ajax`, thus I don't need any `serializeGridData`. jqGrid makes the Ajax call for you. You need just use `datatype: "json" . To set other `$.ajax` option one can use `ajaxGridOptions`: `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }`. You should fix `jsonReader`. See my [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33799091/315935) for `jsonReader` with `root: "responseJSON.rows"` and so on.

Comment: @Oleg I changed the [code](http://pastebin.com/pDhH2jFN) but it does not load data into the grid.

Comment: You should debug the code. First of all you old code don't made `JSON.stringify(data);` and had used just `data:postdata`. Probably you should remove `serializeGridData` to have the same request to the server as before. You should verify whether the server method will be successfully called. You can set breakpoint in the server code for example. In the same way you should verify, which exact format have returned data (if any was returned). I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make HTTP trace. Alternatively you can use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome (Network tab).

Comment: It could be that `root: "responseJSON.rows"` in `jsonReader` need be changed to corresponds the format of returned data. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) and the exact format of the data returned by the server.

Comment: @Oleg Yes, it had to be `root:"rows"`. Though I can see data now, I have not implemented `id` in json reader. Is it necessary? My [snippet](http://pastebin.com/ftxsvsGS) of the working implementation.

Comment: jqGrid **have to** assign unique `id` attribute to every row. For editing of data for example you need to know the id which identify the edited data. Your old code contain `beforeSubmitCell` which code could be reduced to `return {jid: rowid, param: cellname};` after using `id:"JobID"` in `jsonReader`. After using `id:"JobID"` you will see that jqGrid send `JobID` to the server automatically. If you would use `JobID` instead of `jid` on the server side then you can reduce `beforeSubmitCell` to `beforeSubmitCell: function(rowid,cellname) {return {param: cellname};}`

Comment: @Oleg I have used `idPrefix`. Is it the same thing? `(For generation of unique id)`

Comment: No it's different things. `idPrefix` just add the prefix to every rowid. If you have *munltipe grids* on the same page and you fill both grids with native ids from the database then the ids are unique in one database table, but there can be the same in different tables. Thus you can have the same ids in both grids, for example 5, 10, 32. To solve the problem you can use *different* `idPrefix` for both grids. For example `idPrefix: "g1_"` for the first grid and `idPrefix: "g2_"` for the second one. You will have `g1_5`, `g1_10`, `g1_32` in the first grid and `g2_5`, `g2_10`, `g2_32` in second.

Comment: jqGrid will automatically strip the prefix before sending information to the server. Thus the server will don't need to "know" `idPrefix`.

Comment: @Oleg Alright. At this moment, I generate unique `idPrefix` for each `jqGrid` on my single page application. So each row has a unique id. And now, since  I have also correctly implemented the ajax functionality, I hope I don't get row/group-header duplication.

Comment: You should don't forget to return from the server the data sorted by **two** fields: `groupingView.groupField` as the first sorting criteria and `sortname` as the second one. The parameter will be send to the server by jqGrid. After the implementing the latest changes you can use different other features, options and callbacks of jqGrid. For example you can use `loadonce: true` option for grids which total number of rows not so large (<1000 or <10000 depend on the web browser which you use). But all the changes is another subjects. You need first test new code.

Comment: @Oleg I hope I am doing this already! I wanted to share this small [server code](http://pastebin.com/hUFrikSB) with you to verify things. I have also mentioned the query that runs on mysql

Comment: It you make grouping by `Name` and sorting by `FileName` then `order by Name asc, FileName asc` is correct.